# Illustrator paste in place on one artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to past in place on one (selected) artboard instead of all artboards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Edit > Paste in Front (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>)

or

Edit  > Paste in Back (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>)

or

Edit > Paste in Place (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

These will paste in place on the **current** active artboard.

You can then simply move the object forward/backwards if needed.

Comment: That doesn't work in Illustrator CS6. Even when selecting an object on the destination artboard, the object is copied back to its original location on the source artboard.

Comment: Hi Richard, This question was asking about the *same* artboard. If you have a different question, please feel free to post it.

Answer (score 2):

1.- `Command + C` to copy de element.

2.- Select the artwork do you want to place the element by just click it.

3.- `Command + F`, and see what happens ;)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Paste in place Shift+Ctrl+V**
Paste on all artboards Alt+Shift+Ctrl+V

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. As it stands, your answer adds very little to the existing ones and also explains very little. If you can, please [edit] it, to be more helpful.